# Can the number of topics in Kafka scale up as much as number of client?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to assign a one-on-one mapping between topic and client in Kafka, i.e., can Kafka scale up if we want to assign each clientID as a topic (number of clients may be up to millions)? If it is possible, is it advisable to do so?

More importantly, **if such a scalability is not possible, does there exist any other message queue supporting Publisher-Subscriber model that can handle such a large number of topics?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but you lose the resilience of Kafka consumers. Kafka is designed to share the load across multiple consumers so that if consumer processes come and go, records on a topic continue to be processed.

One consumer per topic just means no progress through a topic if that consumer fails (or appears to have failed).

Best to read the documentation carefully to see the design principles of Kafka and decide if it is the right tool.for you https://kafka.apache.org/intro.html

Comment: Thank you! Will check into the documentation